# Validating a predictive model after using propensity score weights

Tags: predictive-models, survival, econometrics, propensity-scores, weighted-data

I have observational data with a "treatment" and I want to use propensity scores to weight the samples.

A predictive model will be built (including the case weights). I will want to include the covariates used in the propensity score in order to make predictions. Specifically I am planning on running various covariate patterns through the model with treatment = 1 and then treatment =0 to estimate the lift from the treatment, conditioned on the other X.

How can I validate the model on a hold out set or through k-fold validation that will take into account the weights? Lets say I hold out a test set from the predictive model. Do I need to use the weights to create a weighted response variable to measure accuracy or AUC or whatever criteria is used to determine if the predictive model is accurate?

Answer (score 1):

If the holdout is representative of the population, your model should work just fine by scoring the dataset and comparing directly. The weights were used to account for over/under sampling and the estimates are created for application against a full dataset.